Rose new buds are wilting and faling
I planted a rose bush 2 months ago. As you see in the images, the new buds are falling off. I used soil 60% garden soil, 20% compost, and 20% sand. It gets 4 hours sunlight daily. I only water when the soil is dry. Applied vermicompost and liquid mustard cake fertilizer every 15 days. I also use imidacloprid 17.1% insecticide every 7 days. The temperature here is 37°C.





What could be the solution to this issue?

No blossom end rot so it can't be calcium deficiency. ;The photos of the leaves are under varying illumination. Are any of the leaves different from saturated green? ;Lastly - do roughen the soil with a fork - it never hurts.

You should have shared much more details including watering schedule, potting media, amount of sunlight it gets and your weather.
Just by looking at it, my first impression was:

Potting mix is not appropriate or drainage problem
Hence roots are suffocating after you water the soil
Receiving higher amount of sunlight

Rose plant needs sunlight, can handle heavy amount of sunlight , provided you give it appropriate environment. It blooms in colder time of the year if you are in the tropical regions. Which means after blooming all winter, summer is its resting time.
Prune the branches short. Fix the soil. It should be well draining, air passing. Check whether total amount of water passes through it or not, if not, the roots will rot.
DO NOT TAKE FLOWERS IN SUMMER. Prune the buds also.
After you fix the soil, give it a time of 20 days to a month to adjust it to the change. Continue watering it only after the soil dried completely. After that continue providing it with liquqid fertiliser or compost with 7 -10 days apart.
